# How to find z by arbitrary x,y coordinates within triangle if you have triangle vertices

Tags: optimization, opengl, 3d, triangulation

Given vertices `V1 (x1,y1,z1)`, `V2 (x2,y2,z2)`, `V3 (x3,y3,z3)` of a triangle T, I have to find z coordinate of a point by it's x,y coordinate if I know that `(x,y)` lies within projection of triangle Tp `(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)`.

Actually, triangle plane in 3D is defined by equation: `Ax+By+Cz+D=0`, and I can find `z = (D-Ax-By)/C`
The problem is that A, B, C, D are too expensive to calculate in run-time:

```
A = y1(z2-z3) + y2(z3-z1) + y3(z1-z2)
B = z1(x2-x3) + z2(x3-x1) + z3(x1-x2)
C = x1(y2-y3) + x2(y3-y1) + x3(y1-y2)
D = -x1(y2*z3 – y3*z2) – x2(y3*z1 – y1*z3) – x3 (y1*z2 – y2*z1)
```

Is it possible to calculate A, B, C, D using, say, opengl shaders? Are there optimized algorithms to find plane coefficients?

Comment: It's a simple linear equation for each coefficient - there is no room for 'optimized algorithms'. I'm a bit confused by the fact that you are looking for the best performance and at the same time hasn't decided which side you want the computations be performed at (like CPU or GPU). How big is your input? Where do you get it from and where do you want to have the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The technique is called Barycentric coordinates but the wiki page is pretty hard to follow - 
See http://www.alecjacobson.com/weblog/?p=1596

```
float calcY(vec3 p1, vec3 p2, vec3 p3, float x, float z) {
        float det = (p2.z - p3.z) * (p1.x - p3.x) + (p3.x - p2.x) * (p1.z - p3.z);

        float l1 = ((p2.z - p3.z) * (x - p3.x) + (p3.x - p2.x) * (z - p3.z)) / det;
        float l2 = ((p3.z - p1.z) * (x - p3.x) + (p1.x - p3.x) * (z - p3.z)) / det;
        float l3 = 1.0f - l1 - l2;

        return l1 * p1.y + l2 * p2.y + l3 * p3.y;
}
```

Code from http://www.gamedev.net/topic/597393-getting-the-height-of-a-point-on-a-triangle/ - carefull about computer graphics vs maths use of Y Z

ps. I Don't know of any faster version using shaders. One quick dirty+solution is to render the triangle using colors based on the height of the vertices and pick the pixel color at your X,Y - in practice this never ends up being much faster on a desktop machine, don't know about opengl-es

Comment: There are too many instructions at those formulas, Martin. Just about same as in my naive approach. I'm looking for more efficient code or at least a hint how to implement that as a shader program (opengl-es or similar)